# Difference between C# and Python UDP Examples

Tags: python, .net, udp

You can find this C# UDP example in various forms in many places.

```
UdpClient udpc = new UdpClient(55001);
IPEndPoint iep = new System.Net.IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.100"), 55001);
byte[] data = udpc.Receive(ref iep);
string req = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
```

When I run portqry, I find that it responds to 127.0.0.1, but not 192.168.1.100.

```
PortQry.exe -n 192.168.1.100 -p udp -e 55001
```

I tried this also using the raw socket interface.  I could only get it to work if I bind to 127.0.0.1 and PortQry the same.

```
IPEndPoint ipe = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 55001);
Socket sock = new Socket(ipe.AddressFamily, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
sock.Bind(ipe);
sock.Receive(buffer);
string req = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
```

When I run the [Python UDP receiver](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication) example using port 192.168.1.100, I find it responds to 192.168.1.100, but not 127.0.0.1.

On another machine, I have a route added so that traffic to 192.168.1.100 goes out to the router and then returns.  In wireshark, using the Python server, I see a packet go out to the router and one come back when I PortQry 192.168.1.100.  Doing the same with the C# example, the packet does not return.

What is different?  The wireless and VPN adapters are off; so, there should only be one interface being used.  I would like to have the behavior I'm seeing in Python in C# so I can see the traffic from WinPcap.

---

I have some additional info.  I've tried this with the underlying winsock library using [this exact code](http://www.binarytides.com/udp-socket-programming-in-winsock/) except to change the IP and port.  The problem is the same.  I can receive only on the loopback.  I've verified the port is being listened to on 192.168.100 using netstat.  I've also discovered the python receive example will accept UDP traffic even when I physically disconnect Ethernet and ipconfig shows no IP at all.

Comment: Have you checked the [documentation for `UdpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient) yet? The endpoint you pass in is for the *other party in the communication*, not the IP address you bind to. Passing in a port number means you want to bind to a local IP address, which is why 127.0.0.1 is bound to. You pass in a `IPEndPoint` instance to the `Receive` method, so you want to receive data only if it was sent *from* 192.168.1.100.

Comment: `192.168.1.100` is not a port, it is an *ip address*. You haven't shared your exact Python code, so I can't tell what exactly you are running. But the example you link to just uses `socket.bind()`, so only specifies the local address. The `sock.recvfrom()` call tells you what IP address data came from, you'd have to filter on the 192.168.1.100 IP address to replicate the C# code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't tell the `UdpClient` what IP address to use. The `IPEndPoint` you create isn't actually used anywhere. You should use it to listen on that IP:

```
IPEndPoint iep = new System.Net.IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.100"), 55001);
UdpClient udpc = new UdpClient(iep); // Set the IP and port
iep = ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
byte[] data = udpc.Receive(ref iep); // This returns the remote IP and port in iep
string req = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
```

This way you receive on a specific host and port and not only on the loopback address.

Comment: I tried this just now.  It's not responding to either 127.0.0.1 or 192.168.1.100.  It does prevent the Python script from binding on that port if I run the C# program first.

Comment: @Todd I added one line in the middle, not sure if it would be needed since the documentation only talks about Connect binding to specific remote, but Martijn does mention this. Can’t test it myself now unfortunately.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference.